# Function to search recursively for patterns in vim

Tags: vim, pattern-matching

I have a text file with simple text lines. I want to create a function for `vim` (and `gvim`) text editor which

```
can be sent a variable number of patterns and 
it should find lines will all patterns (in any order) 
and keep only these lines 
while deleting the rest.
```

I searched the net and found some useful links but none that could do all above:

Following will find and delete all lines not containing the pattern:

```
 :v/pattern/d
```

Multiple searching and highlighting can be done with scripts as `MultipleSearch` http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=479 .  Boolean logic searching can be done with `LogiPat` script https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=1290 . A filtering package is also available but I could not make it work: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2759

To search and keep lines with multiple patterns with AND :

```
":v/.*pattern1\&.*pattern2/d"
```

but I have enter the code everytime.

How can I create a function that recursively runs `:v/pattern/d` to find only lines that contain all the patterns? I expect the function can be run as:

```
:Myfn pattern1 pattern2 pattern3
```

Edit: I have tried to write following code for this function, trying to use Linux grep command from within vim:

```
:function Myfn (Title, ...)
  : let outstr=""
  : for s in a:000
  :   outstr=!echo outstr | grep s
  : endfor
  : return outstr
 : endfunction
```

But I get following error:

```
Not an editor command:   :   outstr=!echo outstr | grep s
```

Comment: Peraps you might use `/^\(.*\(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3\)\)\@!.\+` to remove thos lines not containing patterns 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

with OR

```
:v/pattern1\|pattern2\|pattern3/d
```

with AND

```
:v/pattern1\&.*pattern2\&.*pattern/d
```

any order

```
:v/.*pattern1\&.*pattern2\&.*pattern3/d
```

(sorry looks like you already had this in of your solutions)

Comment: I do not want OR but AND. I have myself give code similar to yours for this but how to write a function which works with variable number of arguments in vim?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command `Keepword`:

```
com! -nargs=* Keepword v/\v<args>/d
```

and call it like:

```
Keepword word1|word2|word3
```

After using the command all lines (except those with the words provided) will be deleted.

Comment: I am not looking for OR but AND. Your code works for OR. Following modification does not find any lines: `Keepword word1\&word2\&word3`