# Not able to filter multiple items from a list in vim

Tags: vim

I am trying following code to filter multiple items in a list:

```
function! Myfilter (...)
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')  
   for s in a:000
     let alltext = filter(alltext, s)
   endfor
   echo alltext
endfunction
```

I am calling it as:

```
:call Myfilter("word1", "word2")
```

However, there is an error since the value in s is taken as a variable and not as a literal string. The error is:

```
Error detected while processing function Myfilter:
line    3:
E121: Undefined variable: word1
E121: Undefined variable: word2
```

And whole alltext is printed without any filtering. Following modifications also do not work:

```
filter(alltext, ' ' . s . ' ')
filter(mylist, 'v:val == s')
filter(alltext, 'match(v:val, s)')
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Delete the words from a list? Why not just use regexes?

Comment: Where is the problem in this function? Why it is not working?

Comment: This question is the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570728/function-to-search-recursively-for-patterns-in-vim), isn't it?

Do you just need a list of words or a list of regexes?

Comment: Did you even read `:help filter()`?

Comment: I read and tried  `filter(mylist, 'v:val == s')` but it does not work.

Comment: `filter(alltext, 'match(v:val, s)')` also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Displays lines in current buffer that contain all of the function's arguments**

```
function! Myfilter (...)
   let alltext = getline(1,'$')  
   for s in a:000
     let alltext = filter(alltext, 'v:val =~ s')
   endfor
   echo alltext
endfunction
```

**Example Buffer**

```
alpha
word1 beta word2
word1 delta
epsilon
```

**Example Call**

```
:call Myfilter("word1", "word2")
```

**Example Result**

```
['word1 beta word2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found following simpler form to work:

```
`'v:val =~ s'`
```